# Prompts for equation label information

Tags: auctex

When inserting an equation with `C-c C-e` it prompts if a label is wanted, if the label is wanted it inserts `\label{eq:1}`. Is it possible to modify this prompt to allow me to enter the label name similar to when a figure element is added?

TL;DR, Any ideas on how to make the prompt to ask me what to put as the label after inserting an equation with `C-c C-e`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is controlled by `reftex-insert-label-flags`.  Its default value is `("s" "sft")` meaning that section labels are derived from headings, after confirmation, and figure and table labels are prompted for.

You can add an `"e"` to the last string to get a prompt for equations or you can use `t`  (not in `" "` quotes) to be prompted for all labels.  My standard setting is

```
("s" t)
```

meaning section labels are auto-generated, but require confirmation from me, and all other labels are prompted for, with their standard prefix provided.

See the documentation of RefTeX for further details.

Comment: Using `(setq reftex-label-alist '("s" t))` gives me `reftex-splice-symbols-into-list: Cannot treat symbol t in reftex-label-alist`. After looking at the reftex documentation I have tried using `(setq reftex-label-alist '(("eq" ?e "eq:" "~\\label{%s}" nil nil)))` but this doesnt seem to work as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: Upon closer inspection I dont think `reftex-label-alist` is what I'm looking for. It seems to add behaviour to `reftex-reference` as apposed to modifying the behaviour of the `LaTex-environment` when `equation` is the input.

Comment: Sorry, I typed in the wrong variable.  It is `reftex-insert-label-flags`, so either customize this or use `(setq reftex-insert-label-flags '("s" t))`

Comment: Thank you! I've spent longer than I'd like to admit trying to figure this one out.